# Flutter splash flicker issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

**Flicker issue query:**

**Conditions:**

1. Install the app from Testflight/Playstore
2. Open it directly from Testflight/Playstore for the first time which gives output like this

**Note:** On next launches it flickers time gets smaller in terms of white screen delay.

**Framework used**: Flutter => Using latest version of flutter

**Implementation:**

To avoid the initial white screen issue I've added the launch image in LaunchScree.storyboard with appropriate sizes.
But still, it flickers while transitioning between Native engine to Flutter engine.

**Requirements:**

We need a splash screen at the flutter engine to request initial data from the server to present future screens without loaders.

**Main function code**

```
void main() async {

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await getServices();
  await FlutterLibphonenumber().init();

  await Sentry.init((options) {
    options.dsn = SENTRY_DSN;
  }, appRunner: initApp);
}

void initApp() {
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      child: YieldTrustApp(StringResource.appTitle),
      path: "assets/langs",
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'), // English
      ],
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
    ),
  );
}
```

> Is it possible this issue can happen because of **async** main
> function?

[image: This is the actual behaviour which I'm facing right now.]

Comment: i have same problem

Comment: @Ali i found the solution, Let me know if you need my help. Here's the email address: babulpatel1309@gmail.com

Comment: Harsh Patel, please make an answer to the question, it make me happy to know your solution

Comment: I'm facing the same issue @HarshPatel could you explain with an anwer that solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution of this issue.

**Issue:**

I was using multiple splash screens in the code. Multiple splash screen means

1. Launch screen which is shown by the core system from the android/ios.
2. Another is the Stateful widget with the splash screen image in flutter side.

So the core process of initialisation of the application, Flutter initialize the all depenedent libraries first then transfer control to the flutter `main.dart`. And for that we use `ensureInitialised` method in the `main.dart`.

Well, i needed two splash because one which is in the native side eliminates the initial white screen and another in the flutter side can help you to call initial resources like, before letting user proceeds to the login screen some APIs should be called. And because of this kind of structure i got the issue of flickering. Now i can't remove the flutter splash screen because 5-6 APIs were getting called at it.

**Solution:**

1. Removed the flutter side splash screen
2. Called all the APIs in the `main.dart` file before calling the `runApp()` function.
3. Above thing resolved the issue.

I'm pasing a code of the `main.dart` for the reference.

```
///Call function which will be needed before initializing our application.
///Ensure all widgets are initialized
///Set system status bar color
///Get all services
///Initialise phone number library
///Call master data to get all required data
///Set connectivity variable initial value
///Init sentry with default settings.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  initProductFlavour();

  await getServices();
  await FlutterLibphonenumber().init();

  await callMasterData();
  isConnected =
      (await Connectivity().checkConnectivity()) != ConnectivityResult.none;

  await SentryFlutter.init((options) {
    options.dsn = SENTRY_DSN;
  }, appRunner: initApp);
}

///Init application
void initApp() {
  runApp(App());
}


///Pre-cache the data to boost up the performance.
Future callMasterData() async {
  MasterSyncProvider _masterSyncProvider = getIt.get<MasterSyncProvider>();

  var result = await Future.wait([
    _masterSyncProvider.getCountryList(),
    _masterSyncProvider.getAppConfig(),
    _masterSyncProvider.getJourneyFramework(),
    _masterSyncProvider
        .getMobileCMSData(),
  ]);

  return result;
}

///Init product flavouring
void initProductFlavour() {
  var appConfig = new BaseConfig();
  appConfig.baseUrl = DEV_SERVER;
  appConfig.flavour = Flavours.DEV;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The launch image keeps showing up until the runApp() is called. Therefor, we should setup all initial configurations before starting the runApp().
Here is my little stuff.

`
void main() {
  // Avoid errors caused by flutter upgrade (before starting up database).
  // Importing 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' is required.
  // https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  AppManager.startup().then((value) {
    App.launch();
  });
}
`

Sorry the reply formatted code's not working. Look so messy.